# Differential equation with integral of its parameters

Tags: differential-equations, integral-equations

I wanted to solve a differential equation involving a term with integration over its parameters. I want to call the integral expression but I get the wrong result:

```
 ysol4 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[y[t], t] == y[t]*x + 
Integrate[y[t], {x, 0, 1}], 
y[0] == 1}, Integrate[y[t], {x, 0, 1}], {t, 0, 30}, {x}];
Plot[Evaluate[ysol4[0.1]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

I know that the result is wrong since the plot is sensitive to x. It should not be since I called the expression that is an integral of x. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's because `Integrate[y[t], {x, 0, 1}]` is just `y[t]` - in other words, it's treating y[t] like a constant in the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, we have here integrodifferential equation, so function $y=y(x,t)$, and  we can consider equation and its solution as follows

```
ysol = NDSolveValue[{D[y[x, t], t] == 
    y[x, t]*x + Integrate[y[x, t], {x, 0, 1}], y[x, 0] == 1}, 
  y[x, t], {t, 0, 30}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

It looks like `NDSolve` can recognize and solve it (?), and we can visualize solution as

```
Plot3D[ysol, {t, 0, 1}, {x, .0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,  
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @khvillegas You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DSolve[{D[y[t], t] == y[t]*x + 
Integrate[y[t], {x, 0, 1}], 
y[0] == 1},y[t],t]
```